# Force keyboard on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-terminal

How can I get the keyboard to be shown on mobile devices?

I already tried a few tricks that did not work, and I'm looking for a proper way to do it.

Comment: Is this for jQuery Terminal plugin? Because I'm working on this right now, I've ask a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859493/enable-disable-andorid-virtual-keyboard-with-dummy-textarea

Comment: You can try to use keyboard written in javascript http://terminal.jcubic.pl/virtualKeyboard.html, check mobile section in the Keyboard plugin http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/mobile.html

Comment: Almost fixed you can subscribe to this issue https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/39 you will be notified when it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here because you have the same problem, you can do same as I did for [jQuery terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) (it will be in version 0.9 until then it's in [devel branch on github](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/tree/devel))

I've created textarea (I've reused my clipboard) and on mobile when click I give focus to that hidden element, textarea is always at the bottom. I've hide it by creating a mask with higher z-index then text area (opacity and clip don't work when there is focus on textarea). One note you can't do delay (setTimeout) when you focus, focus need to came directly from the real event.